# How do you count the amount of numbers when the input is given separated by spaces, ended with a letter?

Tags: java, input, while-loop, java.util.scanner, counting

I'm quite new to java.
I'm trying out some things for a project but I don't get why this does not work.
The goal here is to let the user input numbers separated by spaces and end with a letter. The program then needs to count the even and odd indexed numbers and output which sum is larger.

I already made this successfully when the amount of numbers given was a constant, but now I want to make it adapt to the user input.
Because I want to put the numbers in an array I need to know the length of this array. To get this I want to count the amount of numbers the user puts in so I can create the appropriate length array.

For some reason the while loop does not end and keeps running. How do I count the amount of numbers put in?

**EDIT**

I've added in.next(); in the first while loop so it is not stuck at the first input element. This brings me to a further problem however of having two while loops trying to loop through the same input. I have tried to create a second scanner and resetting the first one, but it does not get the second loop to start at the first element. Previous answers show that this is not possible, is there a way to put this in one while loop while still using arrays to store the values?

P.S. The input values should be able to be any positive or negative integer.

Here is my complete code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LargerArraySum {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int length = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter your numbers seperated by spaces, end with a letter");

    while(in.hasNextInt()) {
        length++;
        in.next();
    }
    System.out.println(length);

    int arra[] = new int[length];

    while(in.hasNextInt()) {
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
            int x = in.nextInt();
            arra[i] = x;
        }
    }
    int evenSum = EvenArraySum(arra);
    int oddSum = OddArraySum(arra);

    if(evenSum<oddSum) {
        System.out.println("The sum of the odd indexed elements is bigger");
    } else if(oddSum<evenSum) {
        System.out.println("The sum of the even indexed elements is bigger");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The sum of the odd and even indexed elements is equal");
    }

}
public static int EvenArraySum(int[] a) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=1;i<a.length;i+=2) {
        sum += a[i];
    }
    System.out.println("The sum of the even indexed elements is: " + sum);
    return sum;
}
public static int OddArraySum(int[] a) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i+=2) {
        sum += a[i];
    }
    System.out.println("The sum of the odd indexed elements is: " + sum);
    return sum;
}
}
```

Comment: Which `while` loop keeps running? You've got 2.

Comment: Your while-loop doesn't end, because you do not consume the next int, so you check always the same number. I suggest to use an `ArrayList` for your case instead of an array with fixed length.

Comment: The one where I raise the length

Comment: You could read your numbers entirly as an string and split this string at the spaces and convert the numbers in int. But as said above, it's better to use an ArrayList.

Comment: A tip in general for all future development work: debug your code in your IDE. You can then run your code step by step and check the value of everything. Also, try to write code that is easy to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

add in.next(); in the loop. Actually you don't need array. You can sum even and odd indexed numbers while reading without saving them.

Comment: But he wants to keep the numbers as he did other calculations - look at `EvenArraySum` and `OddArraySum`. So `in.next()` doesn't solve his problem.

Comment: It does, he only checks the index of the input in both methods and creates the sum of odd and even numbers. He could do this all together in the first while loop (without storing the concrete input numbers).

Answer (score 0):

1) Your first while-loop does not work because the iterator is always checking for further numbers in from the same position.

Example:

```
Position     0 1 2 3 4 5
Value        1 3 5 7 9 0
```

At start the iterator points to position 0. If you call `hasNextInt()` it will check if position 1 is available, in this case it will be true. At this moment the interator still points to position 0. So you increase your `length` and do the same thing again, so you have an infinite loop.

To move the iterator to the next position you need to call `nextInt()`.

2) You can't iterate over the same `Scanner` with a second while-loop in that way. If you would correct you first while-loop the iterator would point to position 5 (it reached the end of the scanner). So the check for `hasNextInt()` will be false and the second while-loop will not be entered.

3) The comments already mentioned it, you could use an `ArrayList` for this use case like so:

```
    final ArrayList<Integer> input = new ArrayList<>();
    while ( in.hasNextInt() ) {
        input.add( in.nextInt() );
    }
    System.out.println( input.size() );
```

( or like kitxuli mentioned in his answer, dont even store the values, just count them in the first while-loop)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the nextInt did work, but it did bring me to your second point. Is there a way to get the scanner to start at position one? I tried resetting it or creating a new scanner, but that did not seem to work. I have not worked with ArrayLists yet and I first want to know if this is solvable by using arrays to store this, but ArrayLists seem like a logical next step for me.

Comment: At the time I was writing my answerIi wasnt sure if it is possible to reset the scanner to start at position 0 or not.  Now i can tell you, it is not possible. If you create a new Scanner the user has to input the values again, that does not sound like a solution to me ;)

Comment: So using two while loops over the same date does not work period? I tried using Omar's solution of using an empty string, but that is only useful when using single digit positive numbers. Is there no way to put this in one while loop while still using arrays to store the numbers?

Comment: To create an `Array` you need to know the size of that array at initialization time. You could ask the user for the size (amount of numers he wants to input) or you could use an more dynamic datastructure like an `ArrayList`. If you dont want to process the input values further you could also create your sums in the first while-loop directly without storing the values at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has 2 major problems . The first and the second while loops lets take a look at your first loop .

```
while(in.hasNextInt()) {
    length++;
}
```

your condition `in.hasNextInt()` made you insert input because no variable was initialized with `in.nextInt` but also returns either [true] or [false] so as long as its true it will add to the length variable without prompting you to insert a [new input] .so the code should look like.

```
 Int length = 0;
 int k ;
     while(in.hasNextInt()) {
       length++ ;
       k = in.nextInt();
     }
```

you insert the input into an initialized variable k for ex then prompt the user to further input into k after adding to [length] then the loop will check your condition without prompting user for input.

Lets look at your second while loop.

```
 while(in.hasNextInt()) {
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
        int x = in.nextInt();
        arra[i] = x;
    }
}
```

In `in.NextInt()` you are prompting the user to enter new input once again so you don't need int x.Not even the while loop .However you MUST declare a new scanner in this ex: I call it c .The code should look like this.

```
int [] a = new int [length];
Scanner c = new Scanner (System.in);
for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
if (c.hasNextInt()){
a[i] = c.nextInt();          
} else
break;
  }
```

You must add the if statement because if you get an alphabet in the int array you will get an exception error  .The array a[i] will not prompt the user.

Of course it isn't practical to make the user enter the values twice so a better code to implement without using ArrayList class which I think you may not know very well is by using an empty String .

NEW CODE :-

```
String g = "";
String j ="";
int y ;
int q=0;
int w = 0;
while (in.hasNextInt()) 
    {
   y = in.nextInt();
   g =g+y+",";
   q++;

}
int arra [] = new int [q];

   for(int r =0;r<g.length();r++) {

       if(g.charAt(r)==(',')){
          arra[w]=Integer.parseInt(j);
          System.out.println(arra[w]);
          w++;
          j="";
       }else{
     j=j+g.charAt(r); 
       }

}
```

Another even better code :-You just insert your numbers separated by spaces without a letter ,hit enter and the array is filled.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
String g = "";
String j ="";
int y ;
int q=0;
int i=0;
int w = 0;

System.out.println("inset your input separated by spaces");  
  g = in.nextLine();

while(i<g.length()){
   if((g.charAt(i))==(' ')){
   q++;
}
i++;
}
 int a [] = new int [q+1];

   for(int r =0;r<g.length();r++) {

       if(g.charAt(r)==(' ')){
          a[w]=Integer.parseInt(j);
          System.out.println(a[w]);
         w++;
          j="";
       }else{
     j=j+g.charAt(r); 
       }


   }
    a[w]=Integer.parseInt(j);
System.out.println(a[w]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Omar. You are right about not wanting to let the user input the numbers twice, so I'm mostly interested in your last part of code. This only works though if I only enter single digit numbers, once I enter a number like 21 or -4 the conversion from string to array does not yield what I would want.

Comment: You are right my code wasn't even realistic I made a better one for you instead. after you insert the values insert any letter then it will print the array. a comma [','] is added to your input in the string [g].The array length is equal to the amount of instances you inserted numbers  .Then in the for-loop it stops at the comma and fills the first cell of your array via another empty String j etc..